# Recuperar datos de tabla DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, dynamodb

Estoy intentando recuperar datos de una tabla de DynamoDB que cumplan 3 condiciones (es decir que coincidan los parámetros con 3 atributos que le doy).

Trabajo con Nodejs, DynamoDB y Dynamoose.

Si lo hago con un solo parámetro todo funciona perfectamente:

```
Controller.getDifferencesFromDB(params)
     .then(function(datosDB) {
        console.log("DATOS = ", datosDB); 

     }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
     });
```

Y la promesa que recupera los valores de la BBDD es:

```
getDifferencesFromDB(providerName) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var TermsModel = require('../models/terms.js');

    TermsModel.scan('Name').eq(Name).exec(function (err, config) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(config);
      }
    });

});
```

},

Ahora me gustaría pasarle dos parámetros más aparte de "Name", de esta forma:

```
    var params = {
      TableName: "Terms",
      Key:{
          "provName": provName,
          "productType": productType,
          "language": language
      }
    };
```

Y a la promesa le pasaré los parámetros...

```
getDifferencesFromDB(params) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var TermsModel = require('../models/terms.js');

    TermsModel.query(params, function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });

    });
  },
```

Pero esto me lanza un error porque algo estaré haciendo mal... El error dice lo siguiente:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDynamo' of undefined
at Query.exec
```

**¿Cómo puedo hacer la consulta a DynamoDB con Nodejs pasándole 3 parámetros?**

Con uno y con scan funciona, pero al añadirle 3 y usar query tengo problemas

Comment: Qué librería de nodejs estas usando para conectar con DynamoDB?  vogels?

Comment: Eso mismo iba a preguntar. La librería oficial de Amazon tiene parámetros bien distintos a tu objeto `params`

Comment: Disculpad, se me ha pasado especificarlo, ahora lo modifico. Estoy utilizando dynamoose, pero admito cualquier cambio siempre que sea funcional. Gracias